# Determine table content from jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

Initially there are only th in in the table.My question is that from jquery how to detect if the table has any tds which would be later added at some point of time

```
<table>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>3</th>
  <th>4</th>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Just want to know the table has any tds in it from jquery

Comment: Do you realize that your HTML code is invalid? Tables have a structure like `table > tr > td or th` - not `table > td or th` (and yes I know there's also tbody, but most people omit it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An even more simple query would be this:
`$('table td').length`

Answer (score 0):

I feel this should solve your problem

**$('table th').children().length**

Comment: No, this checks if there are th elements containing other elements.